# PHPmyAdmin not displaying all of the user comment

Tags: php, database, textbox, phpmyadmin, comments

I've created a system that allows the users to enter comments under different images.  These comments are then stored on a back end database - phpmyadmin.

However, whenever the user enters their comment which is more than perhaps 6 or 7 words long, the phpmyadmin database doesn't show the full information, unless I click structure where it is displayed in one long line.

The user has a max of 750 characters, and all the information is stored, but is there a way I can change the view within phpmyadmin so that all info is displayed within one box?  Rather than a line?

The issue is with the phpmyadmin not displaying all info unless each entry is clicked individually - the users comments are there and nothing is left out, but it seems phpmyadmin only displays the first few words.  Also, I've checked the character setting and this seems ok.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It has nothing with character checking. I'm afraid none (free) db management system will show it, that's because the text can be very long and it could make user (who does not expect long texts) confused. You may try, if you can, write your own system, but is it worth effort?

Comment: i think it is not possible but you can through phpmyadmin customization

Answer (score 0):

Well this is actually not a "Problem" or a bug, it's the way it was designed.. Are you administrating your comments only with phpmyadmin or do you have your own backend?

Comment: yes, the comments are only with phpmyadmin.. can I change the view type or something similar?